# ACF Post Object empty return

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have custom post type called "Projects" and inside single-project.php view want to show Posts related to Project.
I have tried to solve that problem by using ACF's Post Object but got nothing from The Loop.
I searched for the solution on Stackoverflow and AFC support page and I could not find a problem.

Maybe this 'Post Object' option is not even created for something like this. I don't know.

Code inside single-project.php

```
if( $post_object ):

    // override $post
    $post = $post_object;
    setup_postdata( $post );

    ?>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

ACF configuration
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W381.jpg

New post configuration
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyDMK.jpg

Custom post type output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4brwS.jpg

In the place of question marks, I want to show Posts related to that Project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have allowed multiple values for the field, obtained value will be in array. And since you have set to return value as post object, the value obtained will be the array of objects. After array is obtained, you can loop through those to show related projects.

```
<div class="related-projects">
    <?php
    $projects = get_field( 'povezani_projekt' );
    global $post;
    ?>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $projects ) ) : ?>
        <h3>Related Projects</h3>
        <?php foreach ( $projects as $post ) : ?>
            <?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- .related-projects -->
```

Comment: Hi @Nilambar. I think there is a misunderstanding. With your code I get "list" of related projects in my Post view. I need reverse thing. In my Project view (single-project.php; I don't know how to better describe it), i want to show related posts.